# Do you know how to install the IFC importer for Blender on Mac OS X?

Tags: python, macos, blender, ifc

I am not able to import `.ifc` files in Blender. When I try to import an `.ifc` file, Blender goes unresponsive.

I am using `Mac OS X ver 10.10.2`. Python ver is `Python 2.7.6`. Blender ver is `Blender 2.73a`

I see that the `http://ifcopenshell.org/ifcblender.html` shows the message under OS X: "Users are advised to use a 32bit Blender and IfcOpenShell on OSX if possible"

I have installed the **IfcBlender for Blender 2.73 32bit OSX** but get a variety of errors including an **incorrect** architecture error.

[image]

I have gone to http://ifcopenshell.org/ifcblender.html and selected `IfcBlender for Blender 2.73 64bit OS X`.

I attempted to use the importer to import the files via Install the Blender add-on by clicking on `File > User Preferences > Add-ons > Install from File`. I select the files, but `Import-Export: IfcBlender` does not show under the import/exports to check off.

Then I copied the downloaded `io_import_scene_ifc` to the path `/Applications/blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.73/scripts/addons` via  `cp -r io_import_scene_ifc /Applications/blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.73/scripts/addons` in the terminal. Now the `Import-Export: IfcBlender` shows, and I can enable it on the import/exports. Once I check off, then `.ifc` shows under `file > import`

When I attempt to select an .ifc file to import, Blender becomes unresponsive. The file I am trying to import is only 25MB on my local system.

I do not know what `IfcOpenShell-python for python 2.7 64bit OS X` from http://ifcopenshell.org/python.html is for or what path to install this (if needed).

Any idea how to get Blender to import ifc formats?

**UPDATE:** I attempted to load a `.ifc` that was about `5k` in size and it loaded fine. **So the problem of loading an ifc has been resolved.** Opening the `25MB` file still hangs. Is there a recommended file size not to exceed for Blender?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone runs into similar problems installing the ifc importer, this is how I resolved:

Copied the downloaded `io_import_scene_ifc` to the path `/Applications/blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.73/scripts/addons` via  `cp -r io_import_scene_ifc /Applications/blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.73/scripts/addons` in the terminal.

Now the `Import-Export: IfcBlender` shows, and I can enable it on the import/exports. Once I check off, then .ifc shows under `file > import`